# Does google colab's GPU work with tensorflow 1.0.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, gpu, google-colaboratory

when I checked the version of tensorflow in google colab notebook it was 1.8.0 which is pre-installed I guess.
I enabled GPU from notebook settings and checked for it through this command

```
import tensorflow as tf
device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
  raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))
```

it gave the desired output

but I need tensorflow 1.0 for my code so I
 installed it using `!pip install tensorflow==1.0` it installed successfully but when i restarted the runtime and checked for GPU it gave the following error

> SystemError: GPU device not found

Did i miss something or is it with colab ?

Answer (score 2):

It would work, given it's just a nvidia-docker container (or probably something equivalent).

Only that you will have to manually install the compatible CUDA, cuDNN and other packages.
It can be a hectic process and I have not personally tried it. Also, you are installing tensorflow package, which is not gpu enabled. Try the same command but with tensorflow-gpu i.e

```
!pip install tensorflow-gpu=1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the cuda version to 8....

this removes the current version:

```
      !apt-get remove cuda
      !apt-get autoremove cuda
      !apt-get purge cuda
      !apt-key del /var/cuda-repo-9-2-local/*.pub
      !rm -rf /var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2/
```

And now install the version 8:

```
     !sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64-deb
     !sudo apt-get update
     !sudo apt-get -y install cuda-8-0
```

And now install tensorflow gpu:

```
     !pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.0
```

make sure u have installed tf version 1.0.

check it works:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    tf.test.gpu_device_name()
```